# cannot download image in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to R shiny, and I want to download the drawn image in my app, but after I click the `downloadPDF` button, I do not succeed in downloading the image. I don't know what the problem is. The replicable code is as follows:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(grid)
library(forestploter)
library(rhandsontable)
library(tidyverse)
library(colourpicker)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("森林图绘制工具"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "选择文件 (仅支持逗号分隔的csv文件)"),
      numericInput("ci_column_input", "CI 列", 4),
      numericInput("ref_line", "参考线", 1),
      uiOutput("col_text_ui"),
      uiOutput("b_ui"),
      uiOutput("se_ui"),
      textInput("hr_ci_label", "HR (95% CI) 列标题", "HR (95% CI)"),
      colourInput("refline_col", "参考线颜色", "#FF0000"),
      numericInput("base_size", "基本字体大小", 10),
      numericInput("xlim_min", "X轴最小值", 0),
      numericInput("xlim_max", "X轴最大值", 4),
      textAreaInput("footnote", "脚注", ""),
      actionButton("plot", "绘图"),
      actionButton("reset", "重置"),
      downloadButton("downloadPlot", "DownloadPDF")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("数据", rHandsontableOutput("editableTable")),
        tabPanel("森林图", plotOutput("forestPlot"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # 加载示例数据
  dt <- reactiveVal(read.csv(system.file("extdata", "example_data.csv", package = "forestploter")) %>% 
                      mutate(se = (log(hi) - log(est))/1.96,
                             b = log(est)))
  
  # 观察文件上传
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    if (ext == "csv") {
      dt(read.csv(file$datapath))
    } else {
      dt(read.table(file$datapath, header = TRUE))
    }
    updateSelectInput(session, "col_text", choices = names(dt()))
    updateSelectInput(session, "b", choices = names(dt()))
    updateSelectInput(session, "se", choices = names(dt()))
  })
  
  output$editableTable <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(dt())
  })
  
  # 更新数据
  observeEvent(input$editableTable, {
    df <- hot_to_r(input$editableTable)
    if (!is.null(df)) {
      dt(df)
    }
  })
  
  output$col_text_ui <- renderUI({
    selectInput("col_text", "文本列", choices = names(dt()), selected = c("Subgroup", "Treatment", "Placebo"), multiple = TRUE)
  })
  
  output$b_ui <- renderUI({
    selectInput("b", "回归系数 b", choices = names(dt()), selected = "b")
  })
  
  output$se_ui <- renderUI({
    selectInput("se", "标准误 se", choices = names(dt()), selected = "se")
  })
  
  # 重置按钮
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "ci_column_input", value = 4)
    updateNumericInput(session, "ref_line", value = 1)
    updateTextInput(session, "hr_ci_label", value = "HR (95% CI)")
    updateColourInput(session, "refline_col", value = "#FF0000")
    updateNumericInput(session, "base_size", value = 10)
    updateNumericInput(session, "xlim_min", value = 0)
    updateNumericInput(session, "xlim_max", value = 4)
    updateTextAreaInput(session, "footnote", value = "")
  })
  
  output$forestPlot <- renderPlot({
    input$plot
    isolate({
      df <- dt()[,c(input$col_text, input$b, input$se)]
      
      df <- df %>% rename(b := !!input$b, se := !!input$se)
      
      df <- df %>% 
        mutate(across(input$col_text, as.character)) %>% 
        mutate(across(input$col_text, replace_na, ""))
      
      df <- df %>% 
        mutate(point = exp(b),
               lo = exp(b-1.96*se),
               hi = exp(b+1.96*se),
               `HR (95% CI)` = ifelse(is.na(se), "",
                                      sprintf("%.2f (%.2f to %.2f)", point,lo, hi))
        )
      
      # 更新HR (95% CI)列标题
      names(df)[which(names(df) == "HR (95% CI)")] <- input$hr_ci_label
      
      df2 = df %>% select(input$col_text, input$hr_ci_label)
      
      new_column <- paste(rep(" ", 20), collapse = " ")
      df3 <- if (input$ci_column_input == 1) {
        cbind(new_column, df2)
      } else if (input$ci_column_input == length(input$col_text)+2) {
        cbind(df2, new_column)
      } else {
        cbind(df2[, 1:(input$ci_column_input-1), drop = FALSE], new_column, df2[, input$ci_column_input:ncol(df2), drop = FALSE])
      }
      
      colnames(df3)[input$ci_column_input] <- " "
      
      # 更新森林图设置
      tm <- forest_theme(base_size = input$base_size,
                         refline_col = input$refline_col,
                         arrow_type = "closed",
                         footnote_col = "blue")
      
      # 更新森林图
      p <- forest(df3, 
                  est = df$point,
                  lower = df$lo, 
                  upper = df$hi,
                  sizes = 0.5,
                  ci_column = input$ci_column_input,
                  ref_line = input$ref_line,
                  arrow_lab = c("Placebo Better", "Treatment Better"),
                  xlim = c(input$xlim_min, input$xlim_max),
                  ticks_at = c(0.5, 1, 2, 3),
                  footnote = input$footnote,
                  theme = tm)
      plot(p)
    })
  })
  
  # 导出PDF功能
  output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "forest_plot.pdf"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      # 重新绘制森林图并导出为PDF
      df <- dt()[,c(input$col_text, input$b, input$se)]
      df <- df %>% rename(b := !!input$b, se := !!input$se)
      df <- df %>% 
        mutate(across(input$col_text, as.character)) %>% 
        mutate(across(input$col_text, replace_na, ""))
      df <- df %>% 
        mutate(point = exp(b),
               lo = exp(b-1.96*se),
               hi = exp(b+1.96*se),
               `HR (95% CI)` = ifelse(is.na(se), "",
                                      sprintf("%.2f (%.2f to %.2f)", point,lo, hi))
        )
      names(df)[which(names(df) == "HR (95% CI)")] <- input$hr_ci_label
      df2 = df %>% select(input$col_text, input$hr_ci_label)
      new_column <- paste(rep(" ", 20), collapse = " ")
      df3 <- if (input$ci_column_input == 1) {
        cbind(new_column, df2)
      } else if (input$ci_column_input == length(input$col_text)+2) {
        cbind(df2, new_column)
      } else {
        cbind(df2[, 1:(input$ci_column_input-1), drop = FALSE], new_column, df2[, input$ci_column_input:ncol(df2), drop = FALSE])
      }
      colnames(df3)[input$ci_column_input] <- " "
      
      # 绘制森林图
      p <- forest(df3, 
                  est = df$point,
                  lower = df$lo, 
                  upper = df$hi,
                  sizes = 0.5,
                  ci_column = input$ci_column_input,
                  ref_line = input$ref_line,
                  arrow_lab = c("Placebo Better", "Treatment Better"),
                  xlim = c(input$xlim_min, input$xlim_max),
                  ticks_at = c(0.5, 1, 2, 3),
                  footnote = input$footnote,
                  theme = tm)
      
      # 导出为PDF
      p_wh <- get_wh(p)
      pdf(file, width = p_wh[1], height = p_wh[2])
      plot(p)
      dev.off()
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Well, *I do not succeed in downloading the image* is a rather vague description of the issue. Instead it would help if you post any error messages you get and a add a description of the issue. At a first glance one issue is that e.g. you use `tm` in the `downloadHandler` but the theme is only defined in your `renderPlot`. Hence, I would suspect that you get an error about that.

Comment: More of a general comment but will help to debug - make a `reactive()` which processes the data and then pass that object to the `renderPlot` as well as the `downloadHandler` - you don't need to write the same code twice.